# Apache unmatched sub domain being caught by a random domain

Tags: apache2

Hi there as the title says for some reason my apache is catching all random sub domains to a specific domain and I can't work out why.

I have a few sub domains at the moment, bgp.example.com login.example.com www.example.com but if i type random letters: akegmeakgmaekm.example.com it always seems to default back to bgp.example.com even though in my config files I have a 000-default file which serves an error page.

If you go to say ekmgakmgkem.google.co.uk it instantly serves a "this page cannot be found" error or similar if your isp has set it up that way.

bgp.example.com is actually a control panel and I don't want just any randomly typed subdomain to end up there and I would like apache to just to 404 or something similar to google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache uses the following process to find the best-matching virtual host:

1. Find a list of virtual hosts that match the IP and port, use wildcard if none are found.  In your case, a wildcard is set in the default virtual host.
2. Figure out if we're going to use IP-based or Name-based virtual hosts.  If only one IP and port option matches, IP-based is used and that vhost is selected.
3. If IP-based matching could not be used (because there is more than one vhost on that IP and port), get the list of vhost candidates (by IP and port) and try to match the ServerName and ServerAlias directives with the Host HTTP request header.
4. If no best match could be found in 3, default to the first vhost found on that IP and port.
5. If no IP and port match were found, try to match a wildcard vhost, such as 000-default.

Based on your symptoms, I would guess that you are using Name-based virtual hosts, and Apache is never getting down to step 5 because it uses the best IP-based match in step 4.  You should be able to fix this by setting an explicit NameVirtualHost with IP:Port in 000-default and a server name that appears first alphabetically.

You can find more details about Apache's vhost selection process [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/details.html).